# How to check two properties in an if condition of an Ant task?

Tags: ant

It is possible to execute an Ant target conditionally by specifying an `if` or `unless` clause. As far as I can see this clause accepts only one property. How can I check for two properties?

This is an example:

```
<project default="test">
  <property name="a" value="true"/>
  <property name="b" value="true"/>
  <target name="test-a" if="a">
    <echo>a</echo>
  </target>
  <target name="test-b" if="b">
    <echo>b</echo>
  </target>
  <target name="test-ab" if="a,b">
    <echo>a and b</echo>
  </target>
  <target name="test" depends="test-a,test-b,test-ab"/>
</project>
```

If I run it, the `test-ab` target generates no output:

```
$ ant -f target-if.xml
Buildfile: target-if.xml

test-a:
     [echo] a

test-b:
     [echo] b

test-ab:

test:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

How to specify an and expression for the two properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. [From the ant Targets manual:](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html)

> Only one propertyname can be specified in the if/unless clause. If you
>   want to check multiple conditions, you can use a dependend target for
>   computing the result for the check:
>
> ```
> <target name="myTarget" depends="myTarget.check" if="myTarget.run">
>     <echo>Files foo.txt and bar.txt are present.</echo>
> </target>
>
> <target name="myTarget.check">
>     <condition property="myTarget.run">
>         <and>
>             <available file="foo.txt"/>
>             <available file="bar.txt"/>
>         </and>
>     </condition>
> </target>
> ```

Comment: This does not check, whether the two properties `a` and `b` are set but whether the files `foo.txt` and `bar.txt` exist. This is not a drop-in replacement for `if="a, b"` the example in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is my example with the use of the condition element:

```
<project default="test">
  <property name="a" value="true"/>
  <property name="b" value="true"/>
  <target name="test-a" if="a">
    <echo>a</echo>
  </target>
  <target name="test-b" if="b">
    <echo>b</echo>
  </target>
  <condition property="a-and-b">
    <and>
      <equals arg1="${a}" arg2="true"/>
      <equals arg1="${b}" arg2="true"/>
    </and>
  </condition>
  <target name="test-ab" if="a-and-b">
    <echo>a and b</echo>
  </target>
  <target name="test" depends="test-a,test-b,test-ab"/>
</project>
```